# How do I save server state between webapp deployments not relying on a database?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, jetty

We have a utility spring-mvc application that doesn't use a database, it is just a soap/rest wrapper. We would like to store an arbitrary message for display to users that persists between deployments. The application must be able to both read and write this data. Are there any best practices for this?

Comment: How about creating a MBean that saves the message? Another option is to save it to a file in a common area.

Comment: A message per user? Or just one message, for everyone?

Comment: @Joel - only one message.
@CoolBeans - MBean still needs to persist somewhere between reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options.

Write something to the file system - Great for persistence. A little slow. Primary drawback is that it would probably have to be a shared file system, as any type of clustering wouldn't deal well with this. Then you get into file locking issues. Very easy implementation

Embedded DB - Similar benefits and pitfalls as just writing to the file system, but probably deals better with locking/transactional issues. Somewhat more difficult implementation.

Distributed Cache - Like Memcached - A bit faster than file, though not much. Deals with the clustering and locking issues. However, it's not persistent. Fairly reliable for a short webapp restart, but definitely not 100%. More difficult implementation, plus you need another server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an embedded database? Options are:

- [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
- [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Just include the jar file in the webapps classdir and configure the JDBC URL as normal.

Perfect for demos and easy to substitute when you want to switch to a bigger database server

Answer (score 0):

I would simple store that in a file on a filesystem. It's possible to use an embedded database, or something like that, but for 1 message, a file will be fine.

I'd recommend you store the file outside of the application directory.
It might be alongside (next to) it, but don't go storing it inside your "webapps/" directory, or anything like that.

You'll probably also need to manage concurrency. A global (static) read/write lock should do fine.

Comment: Would you put it into the Tomcat/Jetty homedir? (/tmp is out because it is volatile)

Answer (score 0):

I would use JNDI. Why over-complicate?